# Cake PHP Admin Dashboard Plugins

Tags: php, cakephp, admin, dashboard

This question is an open ended one. I am hoping to get some opinions from the Cake PHP user community.

I would like to orientate myself with the various options related to Cake PHP Dashboard plugins.

Thus far I have superficially evaluated the following known plugins:

- Maldicore (https://github.com/Maldicore/Admin)
- Brownie (http://demo.browniephp.org/brownie/brownie/login user: demo@browniephp.org; pass: 123)
- Cake Admin (https://github.com/josegonzalez/cake_admin)

Generally the above are very poorly documented and are incomplete from a feature point of view (eg. Support for Tree Hierarchy content)

Just wondering what has been the experience with the above mentioned plugins and perhaps some other Cake Admin Dashboard Plugins not specifically mentioned here.

looking forward to a good discussion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please also try http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/admin
It's very nice documented, relatively simple to use and a very good code base.

Answer (score 2):

CakePhp [user management plugin](http://ump21.ektanjali.com/login) has some good feature for admin dashboard and user management

**EDIT:02-01-2014**

Try [Croogo](http://croogo.org/) CMS build on the top of CakePhp, has lot of features like, blog and pages, custom posts, user management, ACL etc.

Comment: Are you using the free version?  Seems like 1.5 had a big security hole and the flashing html text on this site gave me a headache.  I thought that was outlawed in the mid-90's.

Comment: The 2.2 demo on his site also generated the following error:  
Admin UserWarning (2): filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for /home/ektasoft/public_html/sites/umpremium/app/webroot//img/default.jpg [APP/Plugin/Usermgmt/View/Helper/ImageHelper.php, line 56]

Answer (score 1):

I'm going through the process of finding something too.  The premium version of the [user management plugin](http://ump21.ektanjali.com/login) has some nice features, but I worry about the lack of documentation.  I don't think the free version will allow enough flexibility in templates out of the box.

Another plugin I'm looking is the [Pound Cake control](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bancer/).

I think Maldicore might be good but a little premature at this point.